Running multivariate covariance generalized linear model using mcglm()
i am runnig multivariate covariance generalized linear model for the first time. for getting hands on it firstly i am trying to reproduce the example (6.1) from "Bonat, W. H. (2018). Multiple Response Variables Regression Models in R: The mcglm Package. Journal of Statistical Software, 84(4), 1–30. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v084.i04". But it gives me following error while running..

> fit_ex1 <- mcglm::mcglm(linear_pred = c(form_ex1),
> +                 matrix_pred = list(resp = c(Z0_ex1, Z_ex1)),
> +                 control_algorithm = list(correct = FALSE), 
> +                 data = data)


Automatic initial values selected.
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘forceSymmetric’ for signature ‘"dgCMatrix", "logical"’
Error in model_fit$IterationCovariance : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors


Please help me to understand why this error coming up and way to resolve. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
